# How can you rename the Python.exe in windows Task Manager to a unique name?

Tags: python, windows, taskmanager

I am running python script on a client machine. It is a multi processes application that spawns several processes. However in the task Manager of windows I see all the processes running (see image).

[image: Task Manager]

I am looking to try to rename it to the company name but this seems to be a struggle.
Have tried adding a name to the spawning of the processes, that didn't work.

```
processes = multiprocessing.Process(name="mycompany",target=activateMainProgram, args=(argument1,))
```

Have tried to rename Python.exe to myPython.exe and still python appears in the list.

Is there a solution to do this? There are several clients so to do it manually (manually renaming the processes in Task Manager - if this is even possible) isn't as option.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think you will have to package the Python script as an EXE if you want to change the process name

Comment: Windows doesn't have the concept of a process name in the same way Linux has, you can't just set a name for your process. It will always be the filename or description (as stored in the version resource) of the executable. So you'd have to use Resource Hacker to change the description of the executable in your case.